# laravel select specific columns but with relationships

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent, query-builder, relation

I'm currently optimizing my application and one thing is selecting only the things from database which are really needed.

For example when I'm retrieving a User object I normally do it like this:

```
$user = User::where($attribute, '=', $value)->first();
```

This code will give me back a full user object with all the columns. My users table is pretty big, so I thought it is a good idea to only select the columns which I need like this:

```
$user = User::where($attribute, '=', $value)->first($columns);
```

This is also working as expected. But my problem is, as soon as I specify columns, the relationships of the $user variable are not working anymore, because it is no longer an object.

My question: Is it possible to select only a few columns but still be able to use relations like

```
$user->parents
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
 $user = User::where($attribute, '=', $value)->select($columns)->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add all foreign keys for the relationships you want to get. For example, if you want to use `parent()` relationship, just add the key to the `$columns`:

```
array_push($columns, 'parent_id');
```

After that, you'll be able to use the `parent()` relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to load relationship with selected columns but for that you have to select `foreign keys` of that relationship table.

So here you also have to select the column of `user` table which is foreign key in `parents` table and also mention relationship using `with()`,

For example if you have `user_id` column in `parents` table as foreign key then you have to select `id` column of user while you are mentioning columns array in `first()` method as below:

```
$user = User::with('parents')->where($attribute, $value)->first(['id','email','image']); // also select 'id' for foreign key to load relationship
```

After using above code you can get relationship of parents as: `$user->parents`, and don't forget to put relationship in your `User` Model.

If you have foreign key on user table as `parent_id` which belongs to `parents` table then you have to select that `parent_id` column as below code:

```
$user = User::with('parents')->where($attribute, $value)->first(['parent_id','email','image']);
```